# Python class is loaded twice in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below two files

module1.py:

```
class Test:
    data=None

    def get_data():
        if Test.data is not None:
            print("return existing object")
            return Test.data 
        else:
            Test.data="abc"
            print("return new object")
            return Test.data

import module2
print("1:",Test.get_data(), "id:", id(Test))
print("2:",Test.get_data(), "id:", id(Test))
```

module2.py :-

```
from module1 import Test
print("3:",Test.get_data(), "id:", id(Test))
```

on executing module1.py

o/p:-

```
return new object
1: abc id: 2168979056288
return existing object  
2: abc id: 2168979056288
return existing object  
3: abc id: 2168979056288
return new object       
1: abc id: 2168978913056
return existing object  
2: abc id: 2168978913056
```

Above I was expecting the class will be loaded only once and "return new object" will be printed only once. But here it is printed twice and also i see two different id's of Test class.
Any one can hep me to understand this behavior of python ?

Comment: Are you doing a circular import?

Comment: Technically not circular, as `module2` is imported from `__main__`, not `module1`. One file, two distinct modules.

Comment: The top-level module in a Python program is named `__main__`, regardless of the actual filename.  But another module importing that same module will receive a normally-named module.  So there are indeed two separate class definitions here: `__main__.Test` and `module1.Test`.  Either move the class out of the top-level module, or pass it as a parameter to the second module.

Answer (score 1):

The *file* `module1.py` is being used to define two distinct modules: `__main__`, upon executing the file as a script, and `module1`, upon importing `module1` when `module2` is imported.

As a result, you get two separate class definitions:

1. `__main__.Test`
2. `module1.Test`.

Instead of using `module1.py` as both a script and a module, define a new file to act as the entry point for the script:

```
# script.py
import module1
print("1:",module1.Test.get_data(), "id:", id(Test))
print("2:",module1.Test.get_data(), "id:", id(Test))
```

`module1.py` would then look like

```
import module2


class Test:
    ...
```

and `module2.py` would remain unchanged.

When you execute `script.py`, it will import `module1`, which will import `module2.py`, which will *attempt* to import `module1`, but seeing that `module1` already exists, will not import it a second time.

Comment: Every time we import a module1 we will get separate Test class? If so how can i implement singleton pattern in above example where i want to return same "Test.data" object every time?

Comment: The solution is to stop using `module1.py` as both a script and a module.